# How to do an assertion for a pseudo element in Nightwatch JS

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I need to do an assertion on the value 122
[image]

Currently, I am doing it using
`.waitForElementVisible('//div[contains(text(), "' + result + '")]')`,

here result is 122

Is there any way to convert it into an assert.

Comment: You cannot access pseudo elements with the DOM API because pseudo elements are not in the DOM.

Comment: Is there any other way to fetch the value of a pseudo element

Comment: None that I'm aware of. The only way I can think of is working your way through `document.styleSheets`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.execute()](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/execute.html#apimethod-page) with the document query to extract the innerText value and then in the call back add an assert, something like:

```
.execute(function() {
    return document.querySelector('div#output ').innerText
}, [], function(result) {
    this.assert.equal(result.value, '122')
})
```